# Can't bind and event handler dynamically inside Dropzone.js init function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, event-handling, dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzone.js for uploading attachments to my app and I need the remove links on each uploaded attachment to fire an Ajax request so that on click I can:

1. Destroy the given instance from the server
2. Remove the attachment preview from the drop zone.

I'm also rendering the attachments that are already in the server (if any) via mock ups in the dropbox area.

Currently everything works well except when I'm trying to remove an attachment that has just been uploaded (i.e. before any page reload). In this case, although the preview is removed, the Ajax call is not triggered.

I'm sure this is because the on click event is bound to the remove links that were already created at reload but it's not binding to recently created elements.

I've tried moving from binding the event like this:

```
$(".dz-remove").on("click", function (e) { 
  // my Ajax request
});
```

To this without success.

```
$('body').on('click', '.dz-remove', function() {
    // my Ajax request
});
```

I wonder if you can help me find a solution.

**My whole Dropzone config and init**

```
Dropzone.options.attachmentForm = { // The camelized version of the ID of the form element
  uploadMultiple: false,
  parallelUploads: 4,
  maxFiles: 4 - gon.attachments.length,
  paramName: "attachment[content]",
  addRemoveLinks: true,

  init: function() {
    var myDropzone = this;
    var existingFileCount = gon.attachments.length; // The number of files already uploaded
    gon.attachments.forEach(function(el, index) {
        var mockFile = { name: el.id, size: 0 };
        myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
        myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, el.content.standard.url);
        myDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);
    });

    $(".dz-remove").on("click", function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();

     var attachmentId = $(this).parent().find(".dz-filename > span").text();
       $.ajax({
         url: "/attachments/" + attachmentId,
         method: 'DELETE',
         data: { id: attachmentId },
         type: 'POST',
         success: function (data) {
              if (data.NotificationType === "Error") {
                   toastr.error(gon.attachmentsErrors);

              } else {
                existingFileCount = existingFileCount - 1;
                myDropzone.options.maxFiles = myDropzone.options.maxFiles + 1;
                toastr.success("File deleted");
              }},
              error: function (data) {
                   toastr.error(data.Message);
              }
       })
     });

     myDropzone.on("success", function(file) {
       existingFileCount = existingFileCount + 1;
       myDropzone.options.maxFiles = myDropzone.options.maxFiles - 1;

      //  this.removeFile(file);
     });
  }
}
```

**My form in rails**

```
  <%= simple_form_for(@attachment, remote: true, authenticity_token: true, html: {id:'attachment_form', class:'dropzone' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
      <div class="form-inputs">
          <%= f.input :attachable_id, :as => :hidden,  :required => true, :autofocus => true, input_html: {value: @answer.id } %>
          <%= f.input :attachable_type, :as => :hidden, :required => true, :autofocus => true, input_html: {value: 'Answer'} %>
      </div>  
  <% end %>
```